# Passing a Varible through a form

Tags: php

I am still new to PHP but I have been making good progress on my site. However I seem to have hit a bit of a roadblock. I have a page that has a URL and in that URL there is a category Identifier. so it looks like;

```
www.website.com/createpage?cat=1
```

Now in the previous pages I have been passing the variable from page to page doing the following;

```
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
<a href="nextpage.php?cat=$cat">
```

However I have now come to the point where I need to use a form to process the information. I have a special script that runs on submit using the action= attribute.

If I try amending the link there to like the ones above, it just passes a string '$cat' through. I have read on several topics here that I can achieve the same thing by creating a hidden field in a form and calling it out on the new page like I would with the rest of the information. But in both cases it only passes a string through. If I echo the variable on the form before submission it reports the correct number, and if I put the processing script on the same page as the form it gets further than it does without (i have an error somewhere at the bottom of my script but I was expecting that)

Is there anything special about passing through values on forms that I am missing? Everyone post I read makes it sound simple, but I am struggling to replicate it on my own script.

I can post the script, but it is a hell of a long one.

```
echo '<form action="topic_process.php" method="POST">
    <p>Topic Subject:<input name="topic_subject" type="text"></p><br>
    <p>Post: <textarea name="post_content"></textarea></p><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="$cat">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Create"></p>';
```

Comment: All get paramter will end up in `$_GET` all posted via `method=POST` in `$_POST`, but both will always land in `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: *"through a form"* - what form?

Comment: @Fred -ii- the `hell of a long one` :-)

Comment: you can "hide" variable in the form by putting it inside an input with "hidden"  `<input type="hidden" name="country" value="<?php echo $_GET['myvar']?>">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your form string is delimited by single-quotes, you're sending `$cat` as a string, you have to concatenate it :

```
echo '<form action="topic_process.php" method="POST">
    <p>Topic Subject:<input name="topic_subject" type="text"></p><br>
    <p>Post: <textarea name="post_content"></textarea></p><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="' . $cat . '">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Create"></p>';
```

Please read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) to understand your error

Comment: Thank you. After doing a test Echo on the other script it seems to have pulled through correctly. There are other issues with the script, but that is a going to be other issues and my poor skills.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it into a hidden input field of that form:

First, in PHP:

```
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
```

Later on, inside the HTML form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $cat; ?>" name="cat">
```

This will pass that value to the form processing page as a  POST variable, which can be fetched (like all the other input values) as `$_POST['cat']`

Comment: So this is what my form looks like:
 echo'<form action="topic_process.php" method="POST">
  <p>Topic Subject:<input name="topic_subject" type="text"></p><br>
  <p>Post: <textarea name="post_content"></textarea></p><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="$cat">
  <p><input type="submit" value="Create"></p>';

Comment: sorry, I had forgotten the "echo" in PHP - please try again with the edited version -  thanks @n8bar for putting that in!